# Why we are not using SQL_VARIANT data type mostly, even though it supports all kind of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

The SQL_VARIANT data type can be used to store values of various data types at the same time, such as numeric values, strings, and date values. (The only types of values that cannot be stored are TIMESTAMP values.) Then what is the specific reason to avoid this data type in table??

Comment: Do you do any programming in any other programming languages? Do you use various data types there or just type all of your variables as `object` (or `void *` or whatever moral equivalent is in that language)? Do you want to deal with the fact that someone should have stored e.g. the quantity of items in an order's line items but has instead stored a sonnet?

Comment: Does this help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type

Comment: Yup, John. The link which you shared its helps me to understand about SQL_Variant

Comment: See [Bad Habits to Kick: using the **wrong** datatype](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - it has a section titled **Using SQL_VARIANT at all** - don't use SQL_Variant - it's not a good choice

Answer (score 5):

Flexibility of `SQL_VARIANT` does not come for free. There are limitations to what you can do with variant fields. There are also obvious increases both in storage requirements (you need to store the type along with each value in each row) and an increase in computational complexity (you need to check the type of each value before operating on it).

But even in situations when the speed and storage are not an issue, you get more "maintenance liabilities". The readers of your code would spend additional time understanding what kind of things can be stored in a variant field, because ultimately the values that you read from the database end up in your code, and you have to be prepared to handle values of any type.

This is not to deny that legitimate cases for using `SQL_VARIANT` exist. These cases are rather specific, and limited. Most of the time, one of the requirements is that your program serves as a "conduit" for the data going in and out of the variant field, without interpreting what is in it.

Comment: A nice trick I learned recently from Itzik Ben-Gan is to use `CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, NULL)` in the `ELSE` branch of a `CASE` expression. Will blog about it soon.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I have found your post here: https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/sql-variant-use-case (that's useful, indeed)