# User Defined Datatype to store Int float and date

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2014, user-defined-types

I have a attribute that can have the value sometime Integer, float, Date. Is it possible to store the same in the single column using user defined data types or should I create separate tables for the same?

```
e.g. 

<name,type,value>

<Id,int,12>
<Id2,float,12.02>
<Id3,datetime,'09-09-2015 00:00:01'>.
```

Comment: just use `NVARCHAR(50)` datatype

Comment: But then I will not impose the validation if it's any of these valid type and I guess there might be loss while fetching back the float.

Comment: Use [sql_variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)

Comment: I search for sql_variant but it didn't store timestamp.

Comment: Timestamp is [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), why you need it? `timestamp is the synonym for the rowversion data` and `rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows.`  it is not for storing dates `The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time`

Comment: sql_variant comes with many restictions and downfalls.  I would avoid unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Maybe a XML column is the way to go here.

Comment: If I go with separate table then there will be 4 separate tables only. So To avoid the extra table should I go with the restriction of sql_variant or xml column? May be in place of separate table I go with separate columns but if I added a new data type later, I will need to update all the rows.

Comment: the answer is 'it depends'. what's behind this request? please provide some context and a little detail for the requirement (no, 'i need to store different datatype in a single column' is not the requirement).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type

Comment: @Fred This see this link before, so I get in the doubt that should I use sql_variant or xml kind of thing or creating table is simpler and useful.

Comment: Trying to cram different types of data into a single column is usually a recipe for disaster - be it a quick one now or one that emerges over time. For instance, it's going to completely destroy any ability to index. Columns should contain data of the same "type" - not just the data type, but what *is* the data (i.e. someone's name and a telephone number might both be stored as strings but are not the same "type") - so what is it that unifies these three things and means they ought to be stored in a single column?

Comment: Looking again - are you re-inventing [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model)? If so, be aware that in most contexts it's considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Anytime I see somebody trying to clever with EAV I am compelled to share this article. https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Comment: depends upon how you are going to use it, you can go with user defined datatypes

Answer (score 0):

XML allows you to add any meta data to your value (which is casted to a string actually). A quick and dirty example (better would be to use the proper XML namespaces):

```
      select 'int' AS [value/@type],CAST(12 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [value]
union select 'float'               ,CAST(12.05 AS VARCHAR(MAX))
union select 'date'                ,CAST({d'2015-05-01'} AS VARCHAR(MAX))
union select 'datetime'            ,CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR(MAX))
for xml path(''),ROOT('root') 
/*
Result
<root>
  <value type="date">Mai  1 2015 12:00AM</value>
  <value type="datetime">Sep 16 2015  3:04PM</value>
  <value type="float">12.05</value>
  <value type="int">12</value>
</root>
*/
```