# How to assign a column to a dynamic variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

One column in one table of my database say (Table A and Column A) can be either of Numeric type or VARCHAR type. Datatype is decided dynamically and then table gets created.

I need to create a dynamic variable (@Dynamic) which should check the datatype of this column and assign a different column (column B or column C) to it accordingly i.e.

- If column A is NVARCHAR, assign column B to @Dynamic
- If column A is NUMERIC, assign column C to @Dynamic

I've to do this in both SQL Server and Oracle.

Any help to write a function for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Next time try to provide a 
 [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) with a schema and some data so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
 much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You want assign the column name or the column data?

Comment: I want to assign column name so that I can use that dynamic variable in another dynamic sql

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type

Comment: Can you add some more details of exactly what you have to do?  As it stands, I am having a hard time just understanding what you ultimately want to do.  Also this feels like it might be an XY problem and there might be a simpler overall solution to what you want.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Also, is this for MSSQLServer (the sql-server tag) or Oracle?

Comment: Needs to be done for both. I did it for SQL server. Added my approach in last comment. Do you think of any other approach to do this ?

Comment: @StingyJack apparently he want both.

Answer (score 1):

In sql server you can check column data type

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
      TABLE_NAME = 'Table A' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Column A'
```

In oracle

```
SELECT Type
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'Table A' 
  AND column_name = 'Column A';
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql_variant is a dynamic type in SQL Server. The eqivalent in oracle would be anydata type. 
But if you are using dynamic SQL why don't you store the data in nvarchar as it is big enough for the convertet numeric values as well and you can use it directly for your dynamic SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was a generic question and did not need any sample data to answer.

The approach I am following is:

I wrote a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GET_DATA_TYPE] (@input VARCHAR)
  RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @l_data_type VARCHAR(255)
  SELECT @l_data_type=DATA_TYPE 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE 
     TABLE_NAME = @input AND 
     COLUMN_NAME = 'AssetID' 
  RETURN @l_data_type
END
```

I would call this function in my stored procedures as

```
SELECT @dataType = dbo.GET_DATA_TYPE(@input);
```

I declared another variable i.e. `@FinalType`

```
IF @dataType == 'numeric'
THEN @FinalType = columnC
IF @dataType == 'nvarchar'
THEN @FinalType = columnD
```

Then I'll use this `@FinalType` variable in all my dynamic sqls.

Any other efficient way to do this.

Comment: This is the same approach I use. And I have the base solution syntaxis for Oracle too.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for your inputs. Yes, I would also follow the same approach for Oracle.

Comment: Now Im wondering if you have this solution before ask the question? Because this info would help a lot to understand the question.

Comment: No I finalized this solution after getting your inputs.

Comment: So please consider accept my answer as the correct one or  upvote?

Comment: Already did. But some down voted my question and now I am not able to post new questions to stackoverflow :(