# calling a synonym of a procedure where input parameter is user-defined table type

Tags: sql-server

On DatabaseA I have User-Defined Data Type which is used as input parameter in a stored procedure. On another database (DatabaseB) I am creating synonym to this procedure and I am creating same data type there.

When I call the sysnonym I am reciving an error "Operand type clash: Ids is incompatible with Ids"

Any suggestion how to resolve this problem?

```
use DatabaseA
go

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ids] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [sql_variant] NULL
)
GO

create procedure dbo.proc1 @Ids [Ids] readonly
as
begin
    select *
    from @Ids;
end


declare @Ids  dbo.Ids;
insert into @Ids values (1),(2)
exec dbo.proc1
    @Ids = @Ids 

use DatabaseB

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Ids] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [sql_variant] NULL
)
go

CREATE SYNONYM [Admiral_CentralSystem01].[dbo_proc1] FOR [Admiral_CentralSystem01].[dbo].[proc1]
GO

declare @Ids  dbo.Ids;
insert into @Ids values (1),(2)
exec [Admiral_CentralSystem01].[dbo_proc1]
    @Ids = @Ids
```

Comment: What exactly you need to do?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type

Comment: `B.dbo.Ids` is not `A.dbo.Ids`, even if they happen to be structurally identical. You can't create a synonym for the type either (well, you can, but it won't work). You simply cannot call a stored procedure in another database that uses a TVP, because you can't declare a parameter of the appropriate type. There are almost certainly alternative approaches to achieve what you want, depending on what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass Table variables as parameter in another db.
XML variable with XPath can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Basically tables variant are database scoped

> In order to use a user-defined type (UDT) in Microsoft SQL Server, you
>   must register it. Registering a UDT involves registering the assembly
>   and creating the type in the database in which you wish to use it.
>   UDTs are scoped to a single database, and cannot be used in multiple
>   databases unless the identical assembly and UDT are registered with
>   each database. Once the UDT assembly is registered and the type
>   created, you can use the UDT in Transact-SQL and in client code. For
>   more information, see CLR User-Defined Types.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/registering-user-defined-types-in-sql-server