# SQL Variant data type for a composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis, ssrs-2012

I'm new to sql server and I wanted to know if using a SQL_Variant data type column as part of a composite primary key is a good idea?

My primary key is made up of two columns: **Id** which contains integers and **Key** which can contain integers, strings, and uniqueidentifiers.

What kind of performance issues will it create if I use SQL_variant datatype for **Key** column? I've read some articles about the drawbacks of SQL_variant but none of them really touched on how it can affect the primary key. I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: *"I wanted to know if using a  SQL_Variant data type column as part of a composite primary key is a good idea?"* We can shorten this to simply "Is using `sql_variant` a good idea?" The answer is "no". Especially for a new user. `sql_variant` has ***very*** few *good* uses, and normally I find those are caused by XY problems or design flaws.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use SQL\_Variant data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039455/should-i-use-sql-variant-data-type)

Comment: No, it's not a good idea. Your question would point to the direction of using natural keys, and using them is a bad idea from the start: **natural keys don't exist**. Use synthetic keys without any meaning and forget about a ton of problems.