# Error sql_variant type datetime is not supported

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a SQL insert script of my existing data using SQL Server Management Studio v18.

One of the tables contains a column of datatype sql_variant, where among other types data of type datetime is stored.

When generating the script I get the following error message:

> sql_variant type datetime is not supported at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptPublishException: An error occurred while scripting the objects. ---> System.NotSupportedException: sql_variant type datetime is not supported at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataEnumerator.FormatSqlVariantValue(Int32 columnIndex) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataEnumerator.FormatValueByType(String columnName, Int32 columnIndex) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataEnumerator.GetNextInsertStatement() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataEnumerator.MoveNext() at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExtensionClass.AddCollection(StringCollection collection, IEnumerable`1 enumerableString) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoStringWriter.ScriptData(IEnumerable`1 dataScript, Urn table) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptDataToWriter(IEnumerable`1 dataScripts, Urn urn) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateSpecialUrn(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreate(Urn urn, ScriptingPreferences sp, ObjectScriptingType& scriptType) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptCreateObjects(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptUrns(List`1 orderedUrns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.DiscoverOrderScript(IEnumerable`1 urns) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.ScriptWorker(List`1 urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ScriptMaker.Script(Urn[] urns, ISmoScriptWriter writer) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.SqlScriptGenerator.DoScript(ScriptOutputOptions outputOptions) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

Is there a workaround to export sql_variant data?

Comment: The real question, in all honesty, is why are you using `sql_variant`? It is very *very **very*** rarely the correct data type to use.

Comment: FYI: arguments against sql_variant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9039725/6996150

Comment: Maybe you could work around it by creating a view with a converted value of that column and then export that view data.

Comment: use bcp with native format.